# Mouse click coordinates not mapping to Box2d world

Tags: opengl, box2d, jbox2d

I'm using Box2d in Java with OpenGL, trying to detect if a mouse has clicked on a `Body`. But having trouble mapping mouse coordinates to Box2d world.

I have a `Body` positioned at `20.0f, 30.0f` in the Box2d `World`, but find that those coordinates are not available in my viewport?

When the app is running the following locations are clicked on canvas and output:

```
[00:40:01] INFO (0.05,0.05) // top left corner
[00:40:02] INFO (28.716667,0.05) // top right corner
[00:40:06] INFO (28.666666,16.5) // bottom right corner
[00:40:08] INFO (0.06666667,16.616667) // bottom left corner
```

OpenGL has this view ..

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, getWindowWidth(), getWindowHeight());
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrthof(
    -45.0f * 60.0f, 
    45.0f * 60.0f, 
    -45.0f * 60.0f, 
    45.0f * 60.0f, 
    0.0f, 
    10.0f);
```

The `MouseListener` is attached to a `GLCanvas` and implements `mousePressed()`

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    log.info(new Vec2 (e.getPoint().x / 60.0f, e.getPoint().y / 60.0f));

    for (Body b = world.getBodyList(); b!=null; b = b.getNext()){

        for (Fixture f = b.getFixtureList(); f != null; f = f.getNext()){

            if(f.testPoint(new Vec2 (e.getPoint().x / 60.0f, e.getPoint().y / 60.0f))){

                log.info("Clicked body");

            }else{
                log.debug("Did not hit body");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know which coordinate system Box2d expects, but the default for OpenGL is the `(0,0)` origin at the bottom-left corner of the screen.

Comment: I have that set with, `gl.glViewport(0, 0, getWindowWidth(), getWindowHeight());`, right? How come my bottom-left corner click outputs `(0, 16)`?

Comment: If a mouse click at the bottom-left gives a value close to 0, that is the origin for GL and your windowing system. You have to make sure Box2d also uses this coordinate layout. I can't help you with that though.